# DirectX: How do i change button object's font size?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, directx

How to change a simple button's font size for DirectX library.

I have a guess as below, but didn't work;

`CDXUTDialog g_SampleUI;
g_SampleUI.AddButton( IDC_BUTTON_X2_Y2, L"8", (iX + (2*len)), iY, len, len );
g_SampleUI.SetFont( IDC_BUTTON_X2_Y2, L"Arial", 32, FW_BOLD  );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CDXUTDialog::SetFont` method [does not take an ID](http://www.vis.uni-stuttgart.de/~grottel/nobackup/vislib.doxygen/a00051.html) as its first argument like you seem to assume.

Setting the button's font this way would make more sense (untested):

```
g_SampleUI.SetFont(1, L"Arial", 32, FW_BOLD);
CDXUTButton *button = g_SampleUI.GetButton(IDC_BUTTON_X2_Y2);
CDXUTElement *elem = button->GetElement(1);  // ..or perhaps GetElement(0)
elem->SetFont(1); // Set the font for this element to font 1 that we created on
                  // the first line
g_SampleUI.Refresh();
```